# HTML white background not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, background, styles

I downloaded an already set-up dashboard ( https://github.com/app-generator/django-dashboard-argon ). Of course, after downloading it I tried to customize it according to my needs. I need the background to be fully white but I am not able to change the standard greyish color (right in the picture). I tried the following:

- Inspect the argon.css file and inspect the classes
- Inspect the root colors and tried to change them
- Tried to set the background on the body via the style attribute setting the `background-color: #FFFFFF` but this is working for all colors except for white :D

My opinion is that something is affecting the way white is displayed and the final result is not a simple white but it is something more grey. I attach an example.
[image]

I would like my background to be fully white as it is inside the table(left) but at the moment is light grey as it is on the right.

EDIT 1:

This is the CSS

```
:root {
  --blue: #5e72e4;
  --indigo: #5603ad;
  --purple: #8965e0;
  --pink: #f3a4b5;
  --red: #f5365c;
  --orange: #fb6340;
  --yellow: #ffd600;
  --green: #2dce89;
  --teal: #11cdef;
  --cyan: #2bffc6;
  --white: #fff;
  --gray: #8898aa;
  --gray-dark: #32325d;
  --light: #ced4da;
  --lighter: #e9ecef;
  --primary: #5e72e4;
  --secondary: #f7fafc;
  --success: #2dce89;
  --info: #11cdef;
  --warning: #fb6340;
  --danger: #f5365c;
  --light: #adb5bd;
  --dark: #212529;
  --default: #172b4d;
  --white: #fff;
  --neutral: #fff;
  --darker: black;
  --breakpoint-xs: 0;
  --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
  --breakpoint-md: 768px;
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
  --font-family-sans-serif: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}




body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #525f7f;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Index.html

```
<body class="">
</body>
```

The body is just initialized with no class but somehow already has a greyish color.

Comment: Please add all necessary HTML & Css to reproduce this issue here for others to witness

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the code is just too much to be displayed. You can have a look of everything at the link I attached to the post (https://github.com/app-generator/django-dashboard-argon)

Comment: @CrazyHorse It's a requirement here that you post a [mcve]. Many times, narrowing your code down to a bare minimum example will point out the problem. There's also the problem that if you point us to a third party site, it could be blocked, or otherwise inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks everybody guys! I appreciate your clarifications. I edited with some CSS, I don't know if that can help you